# Loading an html file in webview

Tags: android, webview

Hello I try to load a given HTML file into a WiebView simply like that:

```
webView.loadUrl("http://192.168.0.50/www/TestWebSite/medias/en_fileTest.htm");
```

I get the error:

`"the Web page at http://192.168.0.50/www/TestWebSite/medias/en_fileTest.htm might be temporarly down ...."`

I can't understand why as if I load this exact url in the browser, it displays it correctly.

I also tried to replace "http" by "file" without success.

Why does webView.loadUrl() cannot find it?

Edit 18_07:
Application is always running/debugging on genymotion 2.2.2.

I tried to create a name to access my server, instead to access it via the local ip.
I wondered if the ip disturbs WebView.
So now, my NAS where the web server runs can be accessed from caBBAlainB.synology.me.
That doesn't solve the WebView problem but adds a new one!!! A nightmare.
I cannot access the xml file anymore!
This file is read like that:

```
String siteUrl = "http://caBBAlainB.synology.me/www/AvenArmand/";
String siteDescriptionFileUrl = siteUrl + "site_description.xml";

static class InitTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer> {

   ....

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground (Void... arg0) {
        URL url = null;
        BufferedInputStream buf;
        ArrayList<Language> languages = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(site.getSiteDescriptionFileUrl());
            // So it returns "http://caBBAlainB.synology.me/www/AvenArmand/site_description.xml"
            // Création d'une connection HTTP à une URL
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection)connection;
            int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                InputStream in = httpConnection.getInputStream();
                int error = 0;
                if ((error = processStream(in)) != 1) {
                     //Process error
                }
            }
        } // catch what needed
    }
}
```

When I try to execute httpConnection.getResponseCode(), I get a runtimeException !!

```
Thread[<11> AsyncTask #1 (Suspended (exception RunTime Exception
```

Details are:

```
       // Compiled from ThreadPoolExecutor.java (version 1.5 : 49.0, super bit) 
     public class java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor extends java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService {
```

`// Method descriptor #17 (IIJLjava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;Ljava/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue;)
 // Signature: (IIJLjava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;Ljava/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue<Ljava/lang/Runnable;>;)
 // Stack: 3, Locals: 7
 public ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit unit, 
java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue workQueue);
 0  aload_0 [this]
 1  invokespecial java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService() [1]
 4  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
 7  dup
 8  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
10  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
13  athrow
  Line numbers:
    [pc: 0, line: 29]
  Local variable table:
    [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: this index: 0 type: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
    [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: corePoolSize index: 1 type: int
    [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: maximumPoolSize index: 2 type: int
    [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: keepAliveTime index: 3 type: long
    [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: unit index: 5 type: java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
    [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: workQueue index: 6 type: java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue
  Local variable type table:
    [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: workQueue index: 6 type: java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue<java.lang.Runnable>

 etc..... Do I have to paste all the hundreds lines ??`

So I precise that the code perfectly works with 192.168.0.50 instead of caBBAlanB.synology.me!

PLEASE, I really don't understand anything!

Regards,
Alain

Comment: In the browser of what? Your device/phone? Your emulator? Your pc? And where is the webview running?

Comment: Hello GreenApps, I'm running/debugging the App on a Genymotion emultion device. I didn't tried to run it on a real device. Anyway, I succesfully loaded the html file in the browser on this same Genymotion emulation device.

Comment: You said 'i get the errror' But you did not tell where you got/saw that error? Is 192.168.0.50 the pc where the emulator is running on? You request internet permission in the manifest file?

Comment: 192.168.0.50 is an other PC on my local network. In my application, I also read xml and audio files successfully just before trying to display this html file so no problem anywhere to access this URL. I only get the problem in the WebView and as I said, I can display this html file in a browser running on my target. And As a proof, the error displayed in the WebView (WebPage Not Available. The Webpage http://192.168.0.50/www/TestWebSite/medias/en_fileTest.htm might be temporarly down ....) displays the URL as a link...

Comment: ... Continued: If I click on this link, the web browser is invoked and the file is well displayed. So the URL I pass to WebView is correct and the html file only contains a simple text. I don't understand !?! Does the problem come from local IP access? Does the problem come from giving a specific HMTL file instead of just an URL path ??

Comment: Repeat: You request internet permission in the manifest file?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> Put that in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Of course, as I said, this application is downloading successfully several other files before trying to display the html file so yes, I requested for Internet permissions.

Comment: `as I said, this application is downloading successfully several other files before trying to display`. If you really had said that i would not have asked. `read xml and audio files` is something that i do not connect with network access.

Comment: Sorry greenapps you are right. In fact, I said that first but as the ize of comment is limitted, I had to remove the part of text where it was said. I forgot it! so, the xml and audio files are also located on the remote server. I saw a similar problem report here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210750/problem-with-webview-not-loading?rq=1, which seems not having been solved :-(

Comment: Time to try a different emulator or use device.

Comment: Yes you are certainly right. I have the same problem with AVDs and I didn't have chance to test on a real device. I'll let you know. ;-)

Comment: So I made the test on a Galaxy S4 Active 4.4.2 and the problem is the same!

Comment: A NAS server... You first said that the used ip was from another pc on your network...

Comment: It is indead very strange that your webview can not load the page and a browser on the same emulator can. A typo in permission request? Did you try on button click instead of on create? Why www after ip address? How did you define document root on nas?

Comment: `I precise that the code perfectly works with 192.168.0.50 instead of...` ??? Does it work with ip now ??? Well use ip. I do not understand your log. With code. But not your code. You should give at least the lines starting with loadUrl. It is not from Eclipse?

Comment: Hi greenapps, I didn't replyed more quickly to be sure because I don't understand what happens.... for now 2 days, the html file is displayed successfully !?! Many thanks anyway for your help and really osrry to not be able to explained why it now works! Anyway it's obvious my problem was not normal!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't really know how this issue gets solved. It just gets working. Possible temporarly problem on emulator...

Answer (score 0):

If you are Using local html files from your app itself then try to put all your html files in `assets` folder .

after that use like as mention below

```
    yourBrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

Comment: Hello user, thanks but if I presently use a local IP, it's for test purpose. In real case, it will be on a remote server. Anyway, I tried to put my file in assets and load it as you say, just to see, and it works but that's not what I need to do.

Comment: sorry my bad, as you haven't mention server side, i miss understood this.
if you running server under same network at your home . try  adding port after your ip address 
ex 192.168.0.50:8080

Comment: I had a big hope to solve the problem with your suggestion. Unfortunately not, I get the same message and that way, clicking ont the link from the error message doesn't allow the onboard browser to open the page.

Comment: It makes no sense to add 8080. If then 80.

Comment: adding port 80 doesn't change the things. My server is a Synology NAS so I used their services to create a caBBAlainB.synology.me to see if the local ip disturbs the WebView. same problem for it but now, that's the other accesses which don't work anymore. I edited my post to explain it. A nightmare!

Comment: @greenapps i was using Apache server on local network and if you want to access page on other device ,you need to have port number(port number where server is configured ) after ip address. and also address is case-sensitive for apache. i am not sure whether its same for other server or not.
and for this question i wrote 8080 as ex (example).

Comment: The case sensitivity if forced by the operating system. Not by Apache.

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Put that in `AndroidManifest.xml`